# Archive button in R shiny, activate only once

Tags: r, download, shiny, shiny-server, xlconnect

I have the following code which runs perfectly!. However, I want to restrict the archiving of the data by pushing the "Export All" button to only once per day. I tried to use if statements and not successful. Another fact is the code is running over Shiny-Server pro and different browser sessions will be created. Any Suggestions?.

```
 library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(XLConnect)
library(lubridate)


  cData <- '
Candidate,Party,Province,Age,Gender
"L, L",NDP,Quebec,22,Female
"M, M",Bloc Quebecois,Quebec,43,Female
"M, S",Bloc Quebecois,Quebec,34,Female
"S, D",NDP,Quebec,,Female
"S, L",NDP,Quebec,72,Female
"F, H",Liberal,British Columbia,71,Female
"T, N",NDP,Quebec,70,Female
"S, J",Liberal,Ontario,68,Female
"R, Francine",NDP,Quebec,67,Female
"D, Patricia",Conservative,Ontario,66,Female
"S, Joy",Conservative,Manitoba,65,Female
"W, Alice",Conservative,British Columbia,64,Female
"O, Tilly",Conservative,New Brunswick,63,Female
"A, Diane",Conservative,Alberta,63,Female
"D, Linda",NDP,Alberta,63,Female
"B, Carolyn",Liberal,Ontario,62,Female
"N, Peggy",NDP,Ontario,61,Female
"M, Irene",NDP,Ontario,61,Female
"S, Jinny",NDP,British Columbia,60,Female
"F, Judy",Liberal,Newfoundland,60,Female
"C, Jean",NDP,British Columbia,60,Female
"D, Libby",NDP,British Columbia,59,Female
"Y, Lynne",Conservative,Saskatchewan,59,Female
"D, Anne",NDP,Quebec,58,Female
"M, Elizabeth",Green,British Columbia,58,Female
"M, Joyce",Liberal,British Columbia,58,Female
"F, Kerry",Conservative,British Columbia,57,Female
"B, Lois",Conservative,Ontario,57,Female
"B, Marj",NDP,Quebec,57,Female
"C, Joan",Conservative,Alberta,56,Female
"C, Olivia",NDP,Ontario,55,Female
"M, Cathy",Conservative,British Columbia,55,Female
"F, Diane",Conservative,Ontario,55,Female
"L, Helene",NDP,Quebec,54,Female
"G, Nina",Conservative,British Columbia,54,Female
"H, Carol",NDP,Ontario,54,Female
"P, Gail",Conservative,Prince Edward Island,53,Female
"T, Susan",Conservative,Ontario,53,Female
"Y, Wai",Conservative,British Columbia,52,Female'
con <- textConnection(cData)
cEl <- read.csv(con, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
cEl$votes <- round(runif(nrow(cEl), min=500, max=15000))
TheDataDF <- cEl


ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Archive Data Post on Stack Overflow"),
   #  Button and Alert, we use the alert to control only onetime Archive
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        bsAlert("alert"),
        downloadButton("ArchiveBtn", "Archive All")
      ),

      # Show the table
      mainPanel(
        DT::dataTableOutput('TheData')
      )
   )
)


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  output$TheData <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(TheDataDF,options = list(pageLength = 25,scrollX = TRUE),
                                                              rownames = FALSE,class = 'cell-border stripe')
                                                            %>% formatStyle(c(2:ncol(TheDataDF)),
                                                              color = styleInterval(55, c('red', 'black'))))

  output$ArchiveBtn <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() { 
      paste("ArchiveData-", ymd(Sys.Date()), ".xlsx", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
            fname <- paste(file,"xlsx",sep=".")
            wb <- loadWorkbook(fname, create = TRUE)
            #creating sheets within the Excel workbook
            createSheet(wb, name = "The Arc Data")
            #writing into sheet within the Excel workbook : 
            writeWorksheet(wb, TheDataDF, sheet = "The Arc Data", startRow = 1, startCol = 1)
            saveWorkbook(wb)
            file.rename(fname,file)
      # Create the message for the complition of the archive
      createAlert(session, "alert", "exampleAlert", style="success",title = "Archive Complete!",
                        content = "Data archived", append = FALSE)

    }

  )

  }

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You need to clarify more about the limit. Once per day for each user? All users? Each session? Do you have user registrations? Once for all user is simple, just check the date, then only the first one push the button can do it. If you want once per user, you need some user registration, then you can check date and user info. If per session, that doesn't make sense since people just open a new session.

Comment: @dracodoc, thanks for your comment. Only once per day, session info and data will be the same for all day.

Comment: I'm still not sure about the requirement. Do you mean no matter how many users access the app, the archive can only happen once for all? You can save a counter for current date to persistent storage, once the counter reach 1 for current day the archive will be disabled. See about [persistent options here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html#local-vs-remote).

Comment: @MPaydar I agree with dracodoc - you're not going to be able to do the restriction to one day unless you usage a persistent storage method. For example, make the archive button dependent on a reactive that is only visible when `Sys.Date()` is not in a local csv that is updated on press. 

Another option might be the `buttons` extension for `DT` [#2 here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html) if you can also implement the [buttons().disable()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons().disable()) here.

Comment: @dracodoc thanks for your comments. I resolved the issue by using XLConnect package and save each instance in a timed stamped folder with the excel Workbook also named by the time stamp. Technically I changed the scope of work to solve the issue !!

Comment: @gscott Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Just timestamp may not be enough. In theory two users accessing the app at the same time could generate identical timestamps and cause conflicts. Maybe add a random string after timestamp.